# Unity: plane defined by three points to quaternions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, quaternions, plane

For a study project, I am working on a 3D file in Unity. The aim is to place three markers, draw a plane through the three markers and make a section cut using that plane.
I am able to define the markers, add a plane, and make a section cut. However, as the section cut requires the plane to be described in quaternions, I have to translate the values from the plane that I have somehow and I don't know how.

The markers that define a plane (sample values):

```
Vector3 p1 = new Vector3(1.1f, 2.6f, 3.5f);
Vector3 p2 = new Vector3(.4f,  4.5f, 2.5f);
Vector3 p3 = new Vector3(6.1f, 6.9f, 1.4f);
Plane cut  = new Plane(p1, p2, p3);
```

Currently, I define the plane using [`new Plane`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.html) but I am willing to define it differently (e.g., using [`PrimitiveType.Plane`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrimitiveType.Plane.html)). I only use this plane for this reference.
Next, I add a section cut using an [existing shader](https://github.com/Dandarawy/Unity3DCrossSectionShader). However, this shader requires a PlaneNormal and a PlanePosition with four values, see the [shader screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMGhJ.png).

In short, my question is: how do I translate the three coordinates that I have to the eight values required for the shader?
Alternatively, if another shader is better suited here, that is fine as well.

## Solution

With the help of your answers, I was able to find a solution.
Using three points, I define a plane and store its normal as a Vector4.

```
Plane finger = new Plane(p1, p2, p3);
Vector3 normal = (finger.normal);
Vector4 planeNormal = Vector4.zero;
planeNormal.x = normal.x;
planeNormal.y = normal.y;
planeNormal.z = normal.z;
digitNormals[digit-1] = planeNormal;
```

Likewise, I define the position as the average of three points. Therefore, I have written a function `AvgVector()` that takes the average value of the x, y, and z axis.

```
Vector3 position = AvgVector(p1, p2, p3);
Vector4 planePosition = Vector4.zero;
planePosition.x = position.x;
planePosition.y = position.y;
planePosition.z = position.z;
Quaternion camNormal = Quaternion.LookRotation(normal);
digitPlanes[digit-1] = planePosition;
```

I store the values of `camPos` and `camNormal` in a new GameObject. Later, I grab these values and apply them to my camera.

```
rend.material.SetVector("_PlaneNormal", digitNormals[dig-1]);
rend.material.SetVector("_PlanePosition", digitPlanes[dig-1]);
SectionCamera.transform.position = section.transform.position;
SectionCamera.transform.LookAt(clone.transform);
RelocateMarker(c, 3);
```

I know that I use quite some variables and that might limit the usefulness of these snippits. However, the entire code will soon be online at https://github.com/TimJohDij/marker-maker.

Comment: I have no experience, but it seems like if you could use the [normal of the plane](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane-normal.html) with [Quaternion.LookRotation()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) to get what you want.

Comment: According to the documentation https://github.com/Dandarawy/Unity3DCrossSectionShader/wiki, you just need the plane's position and normal vector in world space. Just need to make sure for normal vector, set W component to 0 and for position, set W = 1.

Comment: You don't even need w = 1 for position. It can be 0 for both. I think it's ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: These fields aren't interpreted as quaternions. Just plug your plane position and plane normal into these fields as if they were Vector3's, ignoring the `w` field. If you're not sure how to get these vectors, read below.**

Let's first take a look at the two quaternions the shader is asking for.

**planeNormal**

`planeNormal` is the direction the plane is facing or the vector pointing away from the plane. 
So if you wanted to use this shader to slice an object perfectly horizontal, `planeNormal` would be the quaternion representing `Vector3.Up`. A more in-depth explanation is the normal vector of a plane is the perpendicular vector to any two vectors lying on the plane.

**planePosition**

`planePosition` is the center point of the plane. Think of it as the slice offset. Setting this to anything other than `Quaternion.identity` would move your plane around, otherwise it will always intersect your objects center point.

**How to Approach the Problem**

Before we can come up with our Quaternions we need to have the `planePosition` and `planeNormal` as vectors. The `planePosition` is up to you, so the rest of this answer will focus on the `planeNormal`.

Given that

1. the normal vector of a plane is the perpendicular vector of any two vectors lying on the plane
2. we can find a perpendicular vector by finding the cross product of two vectors.
3. we can make a vector with any two points.
4. You already have the 3 points we need to make two vectors lying on your plane (we'll re-use 1 point).

So we need to make 2 vectors from the three points you used to define your plane, we'll cross product those two vectors and the resulting vector will be our normal vector.

```
Vector3 vec1 = p1 - p3;
Vector3 vec2 = p2 - p3;
Vector3 normalVec = Vector3.Cross(vec1, vec2);
```

Now, after playing around with the shader, I found that those fields are actually just Vector3's with an extra value. As far as I could tell the `w` value is ignored, so once you find your normal vector, you can just plug its values into the x,y, and z fields.

But to actually answer your question, the easiest way to convert a vector to a Quaternion is using `LookRotation()`.

`Quaternion planeNormal = Quaternion.LookRotation(normalVec)`

Comment: Thank you for the help. Following @Zaiyang-Li's comment, I indeed solved the issue this way so far. However, I took a slightly different approach, calculating the average of the markers and their normal. When everything is working properly, I will share my final solution here.